# How to pass two column list into SQL WHERE condition using python3?

Tags: python, sql

```py
f"""
SELECT *
FROM *
WHERE 
  RECORD.COL_ONE IN {'first_list'}
  AND
  RECORD.COL_TWO IN {'second_list'}
"""
```

The above query does not pair the lists by position correctly.  For example first_list[0] and second_list[0] should be the pair used to return that record etc.  Instead, it returns all possible combinations.

Comment: If `first_list`/`second_list` are variables you need to remove the quotes, otherwise it wo't expand.

Comment: Ah you are correct ty.  But any idea on forcing sql to pair each item in both list by position?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating function to be called in the python that inserted each pair and then made sql query after concatenation.

#sql where query insert
def sql_where(record1, record2):
where = ""
for i in range (len(record1) -1 ):
where += f"SERVER_NAME.COL1 IN '{record1[i]}' AND SERVER_NAME.COL2 IN '{record2[i]}' OR \n"
where += f"SERVER_NAME.COL1 IN '{record1[-1]}' AND SERVER_NAME.COL2 IN '{record2[-1]}'"
return where

sqlText = f"""
SELECT *
FROM SERVER_NAME

```
WHERE 
(
    {sql_where(record1, record2)}
)
```

"""